# Using new System WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

How can I open links in this kind of webview

[image: System Webview]

instead of phone installed browser?

[image: Chrome browser]

EDIT

Using this code doesn't work:

```
public class WebsiteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView webView = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webView);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

EDIT 2

Using code above will result in this:

[image: Inside app]

But I want this:

[image: System webview]

Comment: Um, that's just [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). The rendering engine can now be updated via the Play Store, but from a developer's standpoint, it is still `WebView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare it doesn't work, i've updated my question

Comment: Make sure that you have the `INTERNET` permission. Also, try a URL that does not require JavaScript (e.g., `https://commonsware.com`), as you have not enabled JavaScript in your `WebView`. Beyond that, please explain, **in detail**, what "it doesn't work" means. [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v7.6/WebKit/Browser1) that demonstrates the use of `WebView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare i'm using the right permission

Comment: Try to move webview.loadurl method above setContentView method.

Comment: @PawneshwerGupta not working, same as before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.3.0'
}
```

Opening a Chrome Custom Tab

```
    // Use a CustomTabsIntent.Builder to configure CustomTabsIntent.
    // Once ready, call CustomTabsIntent.Builder.build() to create a CustomTabsIntent
    // and launch the desired Url with CustomTabsIntent.launchUrl()

    String url = ¨https://paul.kinlan.me/¨;
    CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
    CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build() ;
    customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed ;)